# SharePoint 2010 platform giving error like "errors were found when compiling the workflow. the workflow files were saved but cannot be run "

Tags: sharepoint-designer

i am working SharePoint designer 2013. i have selected SP2010 platform. if i am create simple workflow like Log "test", it is giving me eroor like "errors were found when compiling the workflow. the workflow files were saved but cannot be run ".

and if i am select SP2013 platform then it is working fine. user have full control site collection admin access. i have tried in multiple laptops with different user. and even production and development also but it is giving me same error.

Comment: I don't have the answer, but I'm experiencing the same thing in two different tenants, and from two different machines with SharePoint Designer